# Opposite to Django icontains

Tags: django, django-filter

How can I update the following query so that I need to remove u like "29" (u__inotcontains="29")?

```
model1_obj = xx.objects.filter(
    date_generated__gte=1429142401,
    date_generated__lte=1431648001,
    s__icontains="28"
)
```

Comment: Do you get anymore trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Here is the example base on your code.

```
from django.db.models import Q

model1_obj = xx.objects.filter(date_generated__gte=1429142401, date_generated__lte=1431648001, ~Q(s__icontains="28"))
```

To exclude it, use `exclude` query. Your can read the [details here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exclude). The code will be like this.

from django.db.models import Q

```
model1_obj = xx.objects.filter(date_generated__gte=1429142401, date_generated__lte=1431648001).exclude(~Q(s__icontains="28"))
```

Comment: Okay.. so how can exclude u__inotcontains="29" ?

Comment: No, it is `.exclude`. You need to chain the `filter` method with `exclude`

Comment: Oh okay. Thats great. What if I want to exclude one more?

Comment: You can add the `exclude` parameter just like `filter`. 
`exclude(~Q(s__icontains="28"), ~Q(s__icontains="29"))`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it by following:
`model1_obj = xx.objects.filter(
        date_generated__gte=1429142401,
        date_generated__lte=1431648001,
        s__icontains="28").exclude(Q(u__in=[93,95]) | Q(v__isnull=True))`